# Reading System.Drawing.Bitmap into OpenCV / Emgu to find contours

Tags: c#, opencv, drawing, paint, emgucv

My code is divided in three parts: PART 1) Drawing in a bitmap, PART 2) Saving the bitmap as a jpg image, PART 3) Reading the jpg file and find contours using Emgu.

These three parts work separately but I cannot make them work together. Particularly, my problem is how to input the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` of PART 1 into PART 3 which input is an `Image<Bgr, Byte>`.
So far I have tried to read the Bitmap "target" in Part 1 directly into Part 3 doing `Image<Bgr, Byte> imageFrame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(target)` with no success (it doen't identify any contours)
I have also tried to create an intermediate .jpg file (Part 2) they can share with no success either (it doen't identify any contours either).

The only way that I can make this work is:

i) Run Part 1 and Part 2

ii) Open the resultant jpg image using Paint, hit "Save" and close Paint. I have done this manually.

iii) Run Part 3.

Doing this the contour is identified. However this is not a valid solutions since the step ii) is not automated. However this might help illustrating what the problem is.

Can someone help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace Contouring
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //--------------------------------------PART 1 : DRAWING STUFF IN A BITMAP------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), 1);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

            //This is just an example using three rectangles for illustration purposes. 
            //In reality I have a set of arbitrary lines defining complex polygons.
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100)); //rectangle 1
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, new Rectangle(20, 20, 50, 30)); //rectangle 2
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, new Rectangle(200, 10, 25, 25)); //rectangle 3

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10, 250, 250); //bounding box of the 3 rectangles
        Rectangle rcrop = new Rectangle(r.X, r.Y, r.Width + 10, r.Height + 10);//This is the cropping rectangle (bonding box adding 10 extra units width and height)

        //Crop the model from the bmp
        Bitmap src = bmp;
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
        using (Graphics gs = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            gs.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(5, 5, 250, 250), rcrop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            gs.Dispose();
        }


        //--------------------------------------PART 2 : SAVING THE BMP AS JPG------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        target.Save("test.jpg");


        //--------------------------------------PART 3 : USING THE SAVED PICTURE AND FIND CONTOURS ----------------------------------------------------------------
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imageFrame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("test.jpg");
            //Image<Bgr, Byte> imageFrame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(target);

        //Find contours
        Image<Gray, byte> grayFrame = imageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
        List<Contour<Point>> result = new List<Contour<Point>>();
        using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage()) //allocate storage for contour approximation
        for (Contour<Point> contours = grayFrame.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
        {
            //here i do stuff with the contours and add them to the list result
            result.Add(contours);
        }

        //Write to console
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count + " NO. contours have been identified");

    }//endmain

}//endprogram

}//endNamespace
```

Comment: I tried your code (wtih step 2), but program still can't find countours. Are you sure that trouble is in constructor, not in finding contours?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Please do the following: Comment out "Part3". Run the code. Manually open the resultant jpg with Paint, hit Save and close Paint. Uncomment Part 3 and comment out Part 2 and run the code again. You will see how one contour is detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that trouble is in transparent. EmguCV doesn't understand images with transparent. I updated your code, so, now it work without saving. Does it help or you need transparent images?

```
        //--------------------------------------PART 1 : DRAWING STUFF IN A BITMAP------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var blackPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), 1);
        var bmp = new Bitmap(1000, 1000, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            //This is just an example using three rectangles for illustration purposes. 
            //In reality I have a set of arbitrary lines defining complex polygons.
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100)); //rectangle 1
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, new Rectangle(20, 20, 50, 30)); //rectangle 2
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, new Rectangle(200, 10, 25, 25)); //rectangle 3

        }

        var r = new Rectangle(10, 10, 250, 250); //bounding box of the 3 rectangles
        var rcrop = new Rectangle(r.X, r.Y, r.Width + 10, r.Height + 10);//This is the cropping rectangle (bonding box adding 10 extra units width and height)

        //Crop the model from the bmp
        var src = bmp;
        var target = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
        using (var gs = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            gs.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(5, 5, 250, 250), rcrop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            gs.Dispose();
        }

        //--------------------------------------PART 3 : USING THE SAVED PICTURE AND FIND CONTOURS ----------------------------------------------------------------

        var imageFrame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(target);
        //Find contours
        var grayFrame = imageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
        var result = new List<Contour<Point>>();
        using (var storage = new MemStorage()) //allocate storage for contour approximation
            for (var contours = grayFrame.FindContours(CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
            {
                //here i do stuff with the contours and add them to the list result
                result.Add(contours);
            }
```